# Возможно ли конвертирование LONGTEXT на VARCHAR(100) в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица со следующими столбцами:
text1, тип longtext
text2, тип longtext

Есть сторонная отчетная система, которая получает запрос и обварачивает его, например передал запрос:

```
SELECT text1, text2 FROM test
```

Он его преобразует на такой вид:

```
SELECT CAST(`text1` as VARCHAR(100)) as text1, CAST(`text2` as VARCHAR(100)) as text2 FROM (
    SELECT text1, text2 FROM test
) t
```

Соответственно теперь mysql ругается что CAST так нельзя использовать:

```
MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.50-0+deb8u1]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(100)) AS text1, CAST(`text2` AS VARCHAR(100)) AS text2 at line 1
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как то можно изменить первоночальный запрос чтобы запрос системы выполнился без ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

В функций CAST вообще нету варианта для VARCHAR, соответственно, баг в сторонней системе. Вопрос некорректный.